# Changing the withObject parameter of the performSelector before it gets invoked!

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am in a situation where I have to change the withObject parameter value. I have the following code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(refreshScore:) withObject:self.args afterDelay:7.0];
```

self.args is a simply NSString which has the initial value of @"refreshScore". When the refreshScore is triggered I make sure that it only goes forward if there is a value in the parameter as shown below:

```
-(void) refreshScore:(NSString *) argument 
{
    if([argument length] == 0) return;
}
```

This works fine! But I then I have a CCMenu with CCMenuItemImage. When I click the CCMenuItemImage is fired another selector which makes the self.args = @""; (empty). But it does not make any impact on the refreshScore method and it still behaves as if self.args is populated with initial value.

Is the selector of the CCMenuItemImage fired on a separate thread of something?

Answer (score 0):

put two breakpoints (in CCMenuItemImage click callback and in the method where performSelector is called) and see what is triggered first. 99% if everything is alright it will be the first case. Check if the value is really changed

Comment: Thanks! I checked and it seems like the refreshScore which is the selector method is kind of cached or put in the queue for later processing along with the params. If I just use a public property instead of argument parameter then it works fine! Thanks!